# the database is not created during container startup with postgres

Tags: docker, docker-compose

- docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:11.7
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    # ./init.sql (for unix system) 
    # //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql - for Windows
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - //docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

[image]

[image]

When the container is raised, the script must be run.

- init.sql

```sql
CREATE DATABASE example;

CREATE DATABASE test;
```

But no databases are created. I have to create them through the console, manually

Who has any idea why this is the case and how to fix it? (The figure shows that the script is mounted in a container)

**Solution**

- I stopped and deleted all the containers.
- Then deleted the volumes.
- After that, I started **docker-compose.yml** again.
- The databases were created.

Perhaps the first launch failed, the volumes were created, and when I corrected the file, the second launch of the database creation command was not executed, since the volumes were already created for the current container. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does the `docker-compose.yml` file literally say `//docker/...`, with two slashes; do you mean `./docker/...`, relative to the current directory?  Can you provide a [mcve], and describe more about the process that produced the images you've attached here?

Comment: Note that once the database initializes once, and writes files to the volume, it will not attempt to initialize again. You need to delete the volume between tests of the init script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the update, it appears that a previous startup of the database had been done. Once that happens, the volume gets initialized. And once the volume has data, the [entrypoint for the database will not perform the initialization step again.](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1dcdff4b410936b5b11d1e25c6b60a002b2fc9b9/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L284-L312)

The solution is to stop the database, delete the volume with the bad database data, and then restart the database.